# url links in Zend Layout automatically appended by ~username on server

Tags: zend-framework, url

I'm using ZF for my project and my server directory structure is:

```
/ROOT
  __/APPLICATION
  __/Zend library
  __/public_html(I put all the contents of public folder created by ZF here)
  __/docs
  __library
```

I have a single .htaccess file which I put in public_html folder. There are two issues that I want help for.
First,
      the url links I'm creating using $this->url(array('controller'=>'home', 'action'=>'index'),null,true), for example, are resulting into `<a href='/~wethemen/home'>...</a>`, where 'wethemen' is my username on the hosting server account. I checked that in page source. That's why it is not rendering the requested controller and actions as well, may be.

Second,
       Only the layout is rendered and no action. My default controller is 'home' so I get this error when I try to access the site.
        script:''home'/index.phtml' not found in path (/home1/wethemen/application/views/scripts/).

This is the first time I'm deploying a ZF project on server. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'll pour the contents of index.php and bootstrap.php if needed.

Comment: And it works fine on your localhost?

Comment: Yes it did. I somehow worked out a way to run it by specifying the controller directory in index.php. You can see it here www.wethementors.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put

```
$controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$controller->setBaseUrl('/your/base/url');
```

where you find the text "->setRouter" or anywhere in bootstrap, before dispatch() is called.

Edit: if this does not work and you think it is a HTTP server rewrite issue, adding

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

if you application is accessed at http://yourdomain.com/
or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /your/base/url/
```

if the application is accessed as http://yourdomain.com/your/base/url/

Comment: I think it has something to do with the linux server. Some Apache redirection or something needs to be done.